Как редактировать html через JavaScript
Такой странный вопрос, к примеру имеется данный готовый html. К которому у меня нет доступа.
<body>
  <div class="blockAll">
    <div class="block1">
     <p>Блок 1</P>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
       <p>Блок 2</P>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

Могу ли я с помощью JavaScript изменить структуру, к примеру, добавить новый блок к class="blockAll" и т.д.?

Можете, но он сохранится до перезагрузки страницы. Причем через консоль разработчика сможете напрямую манипулировать DOM как вам захочется

Я имел ввиду напрямую не через консоль,а на прямую менять.Т.е. я могу с помощью JavaScript изменять структуру сайта.К самому сайту у меня доступ есть  и JavaScript я применять могу.

Странно, js менять можете а html нет. Даже если так, ответ прежний - js и был создан для манипулирования DOM. Так что добавление блока в html делать 3-4х строк.

Добавить HTML с помощью javaScript можно.
Пример с добавлением блока при загрузке страницы:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<p>Блок 3</P>';
  div.classList.add('block3');
  document.querySelector('.blockAll').appendChild(div);
})
<div class="blockAll">
  <div class="block1">
    <p>Блок 1</P>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
    <p>Блок 2</P>
  </div>
</div>



Добавление HTML по нажатию на кнопку:


let i = 1;
const block = document.querySelector('.blockAll');

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = `<p>Блок ${i}</P>`;
  div.classList.add(`block${i}`);
  block.appendChild(div);
  i++;
})
<div class="blockAll"></div>
<button id="btn">Добавить</button>




Спасибо ,вроде разобрался как работает)
